# How to use Clangd LSP + COC in neovim for Different extension types of Cpp files *.cpp, *.cc *.x etc

Tags: neovim, clangd

For some reason, the project I am working on names some of it's Cpp header files as *.x
It looks like these files are not being indexed by Clangd and I end up with the following error whenever I try to use references, definitions on objects declared here.

```
[coc.nvim]: Error on notification "jumpDefinition": definition provider not found for current buffer, your language server doesn't support it.
```

clangd + coc, works for all other extension types like *.cpp, *.c, *.h, *.hpp. Is there any configuration file where I can add the *.x files as well

Comment: File associations are usually configured on the client side, i.e. in the editor. For example, in VSCode there is a setting named `"files.associations"` that allows you to associate a filename pattern (e.g. `*.x`) with a file type (e.g. `c++`). I'm not familiar with neovim / coc, but hopefully it has something similar.

Comment: In addition, once you succeed at getting your editor to use clangd for `*.x` files, clangd may need help determining the correct language for them (because it supports multiple C-family languages, e.g. C, C++, Objective C), you can do this by adding `-x c++` to their compile commands using a clangd config file (see https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#add).

Comment: Thanks @HighCommander4, I'll let you know if I find something

Comment: For now, I'm using this hack where I do set filetype=cpp manually for files with .x type. It seems to work

Comment: Turns out vim finds out the filetype using the extensions given in the $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim file. 

You can add whatever custom extension you have to this file for cpp to get the intended results. COC will get the details from the file_type while reading the file